# add border and delete values after the total row vba codes

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with vba codes. I want to have vba codes to add border to the second data sets (in column R) and delete the 2 values after the total row (4 total)
Here is what I got so far,

```
Sub Test()
Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
x = 2
Rows(LastRow - x + 1 & ":" & LastRow).Delete
Set dat = Sheets("Table F Agencies Combined").Range("M:N")
dat.Replace What:="TRUE", Replacement:=""
End Sub
```

Now I can delete the last 2 rows and replace TRUE with nothing but I dont know how to delete the 2 values after the first set and add the border to the column R for the second data set.

[image: Data sets]

[image: revised data]

[image: final data]

Comment: I forgot to add that the data range varies by each month so I need the codes to loop through the data set in order to add the border and delete the values accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're better off to treat each block of data separately.  You can run this code repeatedly without losing data.

```
Sub Test2()

  Dim c As Range, r As Range
' 1st block
  Set c = Range("B:B").Find("total", Range("B1"), xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
'c.Select
  c.Offset(1).Resize(2).EntireRow.ClearContents

' 2nd block
  Set c = Range("B:B").Find("total", c, xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
'c.Select
  c.Offset(1).Resize(2).EntireRow.ClearContents

  Set r = Intersect(c.EntireRow, Columns("R"))
  Set r = Range(r, r.End(xlUp))
  r.BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThick

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, it takes out the 4 values beautifully, is there a way you can incorporate the border around second data set column R? somehow it's not showing. Thank you again,

Comment: Ok, I've modified my answer to include adding the border.  Quick and dirty, but works with your existing data layout.

Comment: Hi Dave, I think the revised worked partially since I want to have the border up to LR cell if you see the second picture, it only has border around the numbers. I can fix the xlThick to xlMedium so its no biggie there

Comment: I included in the third picture how I want to present it and hopefully this is a quick fix

Comment: Oh, I see the merged cell in column B was throwing things off.  Try the modification.

Comment: sweet, it works like a charm!! thank you again Dave! You save the day

Answer (score 0):

**You had a few mistakes in your code (syntax errors, logic errors). I have corrected them for you.**

```
Sub Test()
    Dim dat As Range: Set dat = Sheets("Table F Agencies Combined").Range("M:N")
    Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim myCell As Variant

    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    x = 2
    Rows(LastRow - x + 1 & ":" & LastRow).Delete

    For Each myCell In dat
        myCell.Value = Replace(UCase(myCell.Value), "TRUE", "")
    Next myCell
End Sub
```